# CNAME is not acting as an Alias on Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, dns-zone, cloudflare, alias

I would like to display the same content of: `example.com` if someone visits `example.net`

I researched and it seems to be possible by simply setting up a CNAME record on `example.net` that is pointing to `example.com`.

I did exactly that, and this is how my setup looks like right now:

[image]

The problem I'm experiencing though is that when I visit `example.net` I see the default Nginx page of the server that is hosting `example.com`.

Why is that? Do I need to set things up on server side as well, to point to the same domain? It's quite confusing to me, what's the reason of CNAME then. I could use an A record for that also.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

CNAME only works for the same domain, for cross-domain redirection you need a web server to do the actual redirects.

Comment: A `CNAME` doesn't do the HTTP redirect even if it's for the same domain. The web server always needs to be configured to handle the hostname. It could be an alias for the virtual host, a reverse proxy to the other site or a HTTP redirection, but the web server always needs to be aware of it, unless it's a HTTP 1.0 style server, where a single `IP:port` can only server a single site. But we aren't in the 1990s anymore.

Comment: I didn't say a CNAME does a HTTP redirect, hth.

Comment: But CNAME can perfectly fine refer to a hostname from another domain, so this is not true, and not the cause for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The web server isn't configured to serve that site when the browser asks for `example.net`: the host name on the address bar is sent to the server in a HTTP header `Host: example.net`. This doesn't happen on the DNS level, so it doesn't matter whether it's a direct `A` or a `CNAME`-to-`A` that points to the server.

If you literally want the server to show the same site, you should configure your web server's *name based virtual host* to have the other domain as an alias. We don't know what server software you are using, but Apache has [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias), Nginx can have multiple hostnames in [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name), and IIS has [bindings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding). Also, every link and resource on the site should use [relative paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp), or the user will eventually be browsing `example.com`. That might be hard, as e.g. WordPress always uses absolute paths, and using relative paths and serving the same site on several domains might [not be good for SEO](https://developer.yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/).

Better alternative would be using a HTTP redirect. This could be done on the same server, but also on any server `example.net A` is pointing to. The server at `example.net` tells the browser to go to `example.com`, and the URL on the address bar changes. Again, the configuration depends on the server software: Apache has [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), Nginx [`return`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return), and IIS's [`httpRedirect`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/)s can be configured in GUI.

Comment: What I've seen a 301 Permanently Moved seems to be the standard implementation for these kinds of things. It's also a good way of doing it, since it's cacheable, and you don't need to maintain a complicated rewrite ruleset for both domain names.

Comment: @Stuggi: Good addition. That's correct.